# How to make, no www multiple domains to one root, in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have two domains which point to the same root and I want to force no www prefix on them:

```
www.tapirhostel.pl
www.tapirhostel.com
```

For now I have something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tapirhostel\.pl$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tapirhostel\.com$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tapirhostel\.pl$  [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tapirhostel\.com$  [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/tapirhostel/.*$
```

When I enter it without www everything works fine. 
Problems start when you enter “www” in front. When you enter [www.tapirhostel.pl](http://www.tapirhostel.pl) it nicely redirects to [tapirhostel.pl](http://tapirhostel.pl) but when I enter [www.tapirhostel.com](http://www.tapirhostel.com) it redirects me to [tapirhostel.pl](http://tapirhostel.pl).
Any ideas?

Comment: Where are the rest of your rules? Those are only conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tapirhostel\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tapirhostel.pl/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.tapirhostel\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://tapirhostel.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```